MLFlow - Is there a way to log all input parameters to a function?
I have a function which is meant to be extendable, and would like to ensure that all input parameters keep being logged without the need to manually check/add them. Is there a way to do this automatically?
def __init__(self, model_name: str, num_classes: int, device: str = 'cuda:0', learning_rate: float = 5e-5,
                 do_layer_freeze: bool = True, extra_class_layers: Optional[Union[int, list]] = None,
                 fine_tune_dropout_rate: float = 0):

For scikit learn models this happens naturally using the autologger but doesn't seem to with pytroch (Lightning). Currently, I am having to do it the manual way:
mlflow.log_params({'model_name': model_name,
                           'num_classes': num_classes,
                           'learning_rate': learning_rate,
                           'do_layer_freeze': do_layer_freeze,
                           'extra_class_layers': extra_class_layers,
                           'fine_tune_dropout_rate': fine_tune_dropout_rate})


You could use inspect to get the arguments that are passed to a function, then assemble them into a dictionary and pass that dictionary to mlflow.log_params().
>>> import inspect
>>> 
>>> def foo(a, b, c=3, *args, **kwargs):
...     _args, varargs, varkw, values = inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe())
...     
...     d = {}
...     for a in _args:
...             d[a] = values[a]
...     
...     for i, a in enumerate(values[varargs]):
...             d[f"arg_{i}"] = a
...     
...     d.update(values[varkw])
...     
...     return d
... 
>>> print(foo(1, 2, 3, 4, dog = "cat"))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'arg_0': 4, 'dog': 'cat'}

